# Python Openpyxl - Modify excel file and its value

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I get an exported Excel file displaying ProductItems, locations, and some sale numbers.

Now, the problem is that the ProductItems and Locations are all in one column, indented a bit, like this:

```
ProductItem_1
   Location_a | Quantity  | Price
   Location_b | Quantity  | Price
   Location_c | Quantity  | Price
   (110 locations total)
ProductItem_2
   Location_a | Quantity  | Price
   Location_b | Quantity  | Price
   Location_c | Quantity  | Price
ProductItem_1
   Location_a | Quantity  | Price
   Location_b | Quantity  | Price
   Location_c | Quantity  | Price
```

.... etc... like 150 ProductItems x 110 Locations ...

My idea is to Insert a Column to the left, it would be empty, and then copy the name of ProductItem name to every row, like this:

```
ProductItem_1 | Location_a | QuantityVal  | PriceVal
ProductItem_1 | Location_b | QuantityVal  | PriceVal
ProductItem_1 | Location_c | QuantityVal  | PriceVal
ProductItem_2 | Location_a | QuantityVal  | PriceVal
ProductItem_2 | Location_b | QuantityVal  | PriceVal
ProductItem_2 | Location_c | QuantityVal  | PriceVal
ProductItem_3 | Location_a | QuantityVal  | PriceVal
ProductItem_3 | Location_b | QuantityVal  | PriceVal
ProductItem_3 | Location_c | QuantityVal  | PriceVal
```

How do I accomplish this? I am attaching a screenshot of the Excel file... Any idea how to tackle this with Openpyxl in Python?
Thank you
[image]

Desired outcome would look like this:
[image]

Comment: You should include at least some code.

Comment: I don't have any code. I am asking for help and directions.

Comment: That is not what StackOverflow is for.

Answer (score 0):

This example produces the requested format based on your before image and includes rows 1 -4 from the original sheet unchanged.
Basically the code loops through the rows from row 5, the header row for the data in columns B, C, D, and E. It moves each range from A to E across by 1 so that column A is then empty, and sets the value in that row's column A to the value of the latest determined 'ProductItems' using variable 'colA_val'.

'ProductItems' is determined by the leading spaces in the cell text set by the variable 'num_indent'. Judging from the image has 1 leading space. If there is a more definitive way to determine the 'ProductItems' row this part can be changed.

The following steps are optional

1. After the data is moved 1 column across a loop is used to apply the column widths 1 across so the Headers retain the same width as before. Column A is slighly reduced in width since the larger width text in now in Column B.
2. Cell B5 in the header row has an outline border added. The cell contains no text as this is not specified in the question.

...

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side

filename = "openpyxl2.xlsx"

# Open workbook and select sheet
wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.active

### Loop the cells
colA_val = '' # Hold the text value to enter in to Col A
col_width = {} # This dict holds the column dimenions so the col widths can be readjusted
num_indent = 1 # How many leading spaces for the 'ProductItems' cell

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=5, max_row=ws.max_row):
    cur_row =row[0].row
    row_colA_value = row[0].value
    ### If this is a row with data
    if row_colA_value is not None:
        ### Determine if 'ProductItems' row from the leading spaces, set by 'num_indent'
        leading_spaces = len(row_colA_value) - len(row_colA_value.lstrip(' '))
        ### Is current row a ProductItems row, if so get details and delete row
        if leading_spaces == num_indent:
            ### One off row 5 header adjustment and column widths collection
            if not col_width:
                ### Adjust header row 5 one column across
                ws.move_range(f'A{cur_row - 1}:E{cur_row - 1}', cols=1)
                ### Get column dimensions 
                for x in range(ws.max_column-1):
                    col_width[row[x].column] = ws.column_dimensions[row[x].column_letter].width
            ### Get next ProductItem name
            colA_val = row_colA_value.lstrip()
            ### Delete the row the ProductItem was on
            ws.delete_rows(cur_row)

        ### move name, units, sales etc cells 1 column across
        ws.move_range(f'A{cur_row}:E{cur_row}', cols=1)
        ### Enter the ProductItem name into cell in column A
        ws.cell(row=cur_row, column=1).value = colA_val


### Reset the column widths using the sizes saved in the col_width dictionary
for c, d in col_width.items():
    ### Adjust Column A to be a little smaller than before
    if c == 1:
        ws.column_dimensions['A'].width = d - 10
    ### Set the columns to the same width as before
    ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(c + 1)].width = d

### Add Text and Border to header section cell B5
ws.cell(row=5, column=2).value = 'Enter text here'

med_border = Border(left=Side(style='medium'),
                     right=Side(style='medium'),
                     top=Side(style='medium'),
                     bottom=Side(style='medium'))
ws.cell(row=5, column=2).border = med_border

wb.save('out_' + filename)
```

Comment: Thank you moken. But this is not what I need. There are many productItems in the document, not just one. Thanks though

Comment: @Volkan, the idea remains the same just adjust how the 'productItems' row is detected. From image 1 it seems those rows have a 1 space indent so for lack of any other determining factor I've changed the code to use that. If there is some other better way to determine these rows then update the code to suit.